# Visual studio 2015 debugging issue "visual studio 2015 remote debugger has stopped working"

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, windows-7-x64

I am getting this issue while debugging in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 asp .net core project. I am not able to step into even a single line of code. As soon as I press F10, I get the following window:

[image: First message]

The Visual Studio gets hanged and I get following message:

[image: Second message]

Now if I click "Close the program", I get third message window:

[image: Third message]

After I click Ok, the final message alert I get is this:

[image]

I can see this issue with the simple dot net **core** web (created new project with default template) application project, however I can debug the normal asp .net web application project.

If I look at the windows event viewer, I see following 2 errors:

1. The description for Event ID 1002 from source Visual Studio Remote Debugger cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

The remote debugger has encountered a serious internal error, and must abort the remote debugging session. Please restart debugging.

2. Faulting application name: msvsmon.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x576851c6
   Faulting module name: vsdebugeng.manimpl.ni.dll, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d8f
   Exception code: 0xc0000005
   Fault offset: 0x00000000000708ce
   Faulting process id: 0x25ec
   Faulting application start time: 0x01d2466d7ebb9ba2
   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe
   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\vsdebugeng.manimpl\a6c75970262308829c3cb73849e32197\vsdebugeng.manimpl.ni.dll
   Report Id: e12f7fe4-b260-11e6-b4dc-fc59422f8ce2

PS
Visual Studio 2015 Version: 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Windows Version : Windows 7 64 bit SP1